# How to find number of abelian subgroups of diheral group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

How to find number of abelian subgroups of diheral group $D_n $?

Attempt: I have counter-examples for $n=1,2$ so I know that it isn't true for $n<3$. Is it true for $n\ge 3$? How do you know this?

Comment: What do you mean, you have "counter-examples"? The question asks for the number of abelian subgroups. The answer for each $n$ is at least $1$ because of $\{e\}$. Also, does your $D_n$ have $2n$ elements? Because the notation is ambiguous.

Comment: Please tell me like in D4 we Kelvin 4 group which is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: any element $a$ of order $2$ generates the subgroup $\{e,a\}$ where $e$ is the identity. A subgroup of order 2 is obviously abelian.

Hint 2: $D_n$ contains a subgroup that is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$. This is also abelian.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers I have three further hints:

*Hint 3*: by Lagrange, the order of a subgroup divides $2n$.

*Hint 4*: For $n$ odd, all abelian subgroups are cyclic. For $n$ even, every abelian subgroup is either cyclic or isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

*Hint 5*: This site offers even a classification of all possible subgroups of $D_n$. Keith Conrad has written a nice note on this topic.

Comment: Please tell me like in D4 we Kelvin 4 group which is abelian. I have read that hint 5 source can you put it in more simple form. I am not able to understand that!!

Comment: @user416571 $D_{2n}$ has a copy of the Klein four group $C_2\times C_2$ generated by the unique $180^\circ$ rotation and any flip.